# Как запретить тире вначале и конце строки?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, javascript

Есть паттерн для проверки принятой строки

```
^([a-zа-я-]+)$
```

Как ограничить ввод слов вида:

- слово-;
- -слово;
- сло--во?

Т.е. нужно запретить использовать тире по краям строки, а так же тире должно встречаться только один раз в строке от начала строки до ее конца.

Comment: ^([a-zа-я]+\-?[a-zа-я]+)$

Comment: ах да, что то я и не подумал про такой вариант. Просто думал что там с подсчетом нужно делать =)

Comment: @Etki `\S`

Comment: @eicto, по условиям всякие 0-9 не должны входить.